# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: “Function is not implemented.”

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro, dbf

In order to automate the work of employees, the task was to integrate customer records automatically. The client base is maintained in the program with the database foxpro (dbf). I am trying to manually make a test record in the database, but when adding values ​​to one of the fields, an error appears:

```
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Function is not implemented."
```

I create a class object to work with the database:

```
 WDBF db = new WDBF();

    db.CreateOleDbCommand("INSERT INTO CLNDATES (" +
        "CLIENT_CODE, " +
        "LAST_NAME, " +
        "FIRST_NAME, " +
        "FAMILY, " +
        "HOME_PH_NUMBER," +

        "OFFICE_PH_NUMBER ," +
        "CARD_CODE, " +
        "ADD_DATES ," +                
        "CONTRACT,"+
        "CREDIT," +

        "PROC_T," +
        "PROC_O," +
        "MAIL," +
        "FILE_PHOTO, " +
        "RISK," +

        "WORKPLACE," +
        "KDG," +
        "NATIONALITY," +
        "REGION," +
        "ADDRESS," +

        "MG," +
        "INSURER_CODE," +
        "BONUSTYPE," +
        "DISCOUNTCARD," +
        "BONUSCOMMENT," +

        "DOCTOR," +
        "POST," +
        "POSTDATE," +
        "VILLAGE," +
        "DOGOVOR_FROM," +

        "PASSPORT," +
        "AGENT," +
        "INVALID" +
        "" +
        "" +
        ") " + 

        "VALUES(" +
        "?,?,?,?,?," +
        "?,?,?,?,?," +
        "?,?,?,?,?," +
        "?,?,?,?,?," +
        "?,?,?,?,?," +
        "?,?,?,?,?," +
        "?,?,?" +
        ")");
```

Next, I open the connection and try to execute the INSERT command.

```
using (StreamReader w = new StreamReader("conf.txt"))
        conf = w.ReadLine();

    _connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=vfpoledb;" + conf + ";Collating Sequence=machine; Exclusive=No";
_connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new
            OleDbCommand(queryString, _connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("CLIENT_CODE", OleDbType.Char).Value= 85919607;
        command.Parameters.Add("HOME_PH_NUMBER", OleDbType.Char).Value = 1111;
        command.Parameters.Add("OFFICE_PH_NUMBER", OleDbType.Char).Value = 1111;              
        command.Parameters.Add("FIRST_NAME", OleDbType.Char).Value = "test";
        command.Parameters.Add("FAMILY", OleDbType.Char).Value = "test";
        command.Parameters.Add("LAST_NAME", OleDbType.Char).Value = "test";

        command.Parameters.Add("CARD_CODE", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("ADD_DATES", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("CONTRACT", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("CREDIT", OleDbType.Double).Value = 0;
        command.Parameters.Add("PROC_T", OleDbType.Double).Value = 0;
        command.Parameters.Add("PROC_O", OleDbType.Double).Value = 0;
        command.Parameters.Add("MAIL", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("FILE_PHOTO", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("RISK", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("WORKPLACE", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("KDG", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("NATIONALITY", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("REGION", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("ADDRESS", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("MG", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";

        command.Parameters.Add("INSURER_CODE", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("BONUSTYPE", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("DISCOUNTCARD", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("BONUSCOMMENT", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("DOCTOR", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("POST", OleDbType.Char).Value = "";
        command.Parameters.Add("POSTDATE", OleDbType.Date).Value =null;
        command.Parameters.Add("VILLAGE", OleDbType.Date).Value = null;
        command.Parameters.Add("DOGOVOR_FROM", OleDbType.Date).Value = null;
        command.Parameters.Add("PASSPORT", OleDbType.Char).Value = null;
        command.Parameters.Add("AGENT", OleDbType.Char).Value = null;
        command.Parameters.Add("INVALID", OleDbType.Char).Value = null;






        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Error appears when adding

```
command.Parameters.Add("INVALID", OleDbType.Char).Value = null;
```

When adding an empty string, the error remains:

```
command.Parameters.Add ("INVALID", OleDbType.Char) .Value = "";
```

Went through different types of data, but the error does not go anywhere. What could be the problem? Sorry, my english is bad.

***UPD1:***

I tried to add rows to another table from the same software. Inserted without errors. Made changes to the code in order not to list all the columns, but fill in only the necessary ones.

```
    db.CreateOleDbCommand("INSERT INTO cln_actions (CLIENT_CODE) " + "VALUES(?)");
public void CreateOleDbCommand(string queryString)
    {
        if(_connection != null)
        {
            _connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new
                OleDbCommand(queryString, _connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("[CLIENT_CODE]", OleDbType.Char).Value = "test";
            new OleDbCommand("set null off", _connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
            int x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }}
```

Comment: Does `.Value = DBNull.Value` work?

Comment: Alternatively, what if you leave it out completely ? (Don't put it in the query, don't creat a parameter for it etc". By the way, your query will get a lot more readable if you use an @"string" then you can put new lines in it. See https://csharp.2000things.com/tag/verbatim-string-literal/ final example for an idea

Comment: If i use .Value = DBNull.Value , it gives error  "Field INVALID does not accept null values." 
If you do not use it at all, the error repeats(Field INVALID does not accept null values.)

Comment: What other values are in the INVALID field currently, in the DB? Is it Y/N, T/F etc?

Comment: Empty value only. Field type: Char, 1 symbol.

Comment: What does db.CreateCommand do? And why wouldn't you write the SQL code in a readable manner using verbatim strings? I think your problem is, that INVALID field has a function bound to it (check, default ... - like a trigger with code that contains an unsupported function\code in it).

Comment: db.CreateCommand is a separate method for passing SQL commands to a VFP database. Just for convenience.
I also think that there is a trigger on the INVALID field, but I do not know how to exclude it, because there is no connection with the developer of the basic software.